# React state is changing but is not reflected on screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using the `useState` hook to set `height` and `weight` values from 2 sliders I have to determine BMI.

```
  const [stats, setStats] = useState({
    height: 45,
    weight: 100,
    bmi: "",
  });
```

I also have my `handleChange` and `calcBMI` functions like so

```
  const { weight, height, bmi } = stats;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setStats({ ...stats, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const calcBMI = () => {
    let kg = weight / 0.0022046;
    let heightInMeters = height / 39.37;

    let b = (kg / heightInMeters) ^ 2;
    setStats({ ...stats, bmi: b });
    return b;
  };
```

And the component returns this:

```
 return (
    <Fragment>
      <label>
        Step 2: Input your Height... Current Height: {height}
        <input
          id="typeinp"
          name="height"
          type="range"
          min="45"
          max="75"
          defaultValue="45"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          step="1"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Step 3: Input your Weight... Current Weight: {weight}
        <input
          id="typeinp"
          name="weight"
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="390"
          defaultValue="100"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          step="1"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
        />
      </label>
      // NOT WORKING
      <div>Your Approximate BMI: {calcBMI}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

But in my code where i have `Your Approximate BMI`, nothing happens. I am able to console log the BMI, but it does not show up on the screen. I know that useState is async but the way I have my code I thought would avoid any issues around that.

Comment: Try `calcBMI()` - you should really be referencing the state BMI value and not the return value however, as this will recalculate on every render.

Comment: Isn't `calcBMI` a method? So shouldnt you be doing `{calcBMI()}` inside the jsx?

Comment: If I add the parentheses then it rerenders forever

Comment: Yes. That is what I was thinking. You are calling a setstate inside the method.

Comment: Yup, because you're setting state inside the render via the `calcBMI()` function, which will cause another render and so on. Do what Ethan suggested and call `calcBMI` in the change handler instead and just put the state value in your render.

Comment: If I do that then how will I have the values of weight and height? Sorry, I must not be understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call function that always change the state in your render part of the function.
What you should do is change the function calcBMI so that it returns the new BMI, and each time height or weight is changed, the bmi is changed accordingly.
Also, states with objects can be tricky, so in this situation I suggest to split the state into multiple variables

```
  const [ weight, setWeight ] = useState(45);
  const [ height, setHeight ] = useState(100);

  const calcBMI = () => {
    let kg = weight / 0.0022046;
    let heightInMeters = height / 39.37;

    let b = kg / (heightInMeters ** 2);
    return b;
  };
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <label>
        Step 2: Input your Height... Current Height: {height}
        <input
          id="typeinp"
          name="height"
          type="range"
          min="45"
          max="75"
          value={height}
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          step="1"
          onChange={(e) => setHeight(e.target.value)}
          aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Step 3: Input your Weight... Current Weight: {weight}
        <input
          id="typeinp"
          name="weight"
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="390"
          value={weight}
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          step="1"
          onChange={(e) => setWeight(e.target.value)}
          aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
        />
      </label>
      // NOT WORKING
      <div>Your Approximate BMI: {calcBMI()}</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much. That did it. I don't know why I didn't realize this before

Comment: Any idea though why only the second slider will cause the BMI to be recalculated?

Comment: And the BMI is different every time even when using the same weight and height.

Comment: My bad, I didn't consider the object state, which can be sometimes tricky to manage. I updated my answer, it should work correctly now.

Comment: It looks like that fixed the inconsistencies but the first slider still doesn't update BMI :/ . As I move the first slider, it just console.logs the old BMI over and over again

Comment: Try setting the value of the input as the values of the two state variables (updated answer)

Comment: Tried it but still behaving the same

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a playground (I tried the solution in https://p33c0.csb.app/). Post if you manage to reproduce it

Comment: To reproduce, bring the weight to 0 and then try to change the height. On mine, it does this for every number though. I think the issue is from this line `let b = kg / (heightInMeters ^ 2);` In your example, this line is a little different, but I need it to be like mine

Comment: No idea why that happens to you, I can't reproduce it on my machine 

(Btw, I didn't check the calculation before but I think you meant to do (kg / (heightInMeters ** 2))

Comment: I agree, that should be the correct formula but that is what breaks it. It works every time for you? Even with that formula?

Comment: Have you corrected the ^ sign with the ** sign? That might be the problem, since the ^ is not an exponentiate operator

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer with the correct formula, if you can mark it as the accepted answer it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`calcBMI` is a function which updates `stats.bmi`. I think you want to call `calcBMI` in your change handler, and then render `bmi` where you currently have `calcBMI`.